# Create a multi-page table without tabularx

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I have create a multi-page table. Using `tabularx`, my attempt is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\ifdefined\mc
\renewcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\else
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lr@{--}p{1.3cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.6cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{2.1cm}p{0.7cm}}
\caption{Table} \\ \hline \hline
\endfirsthead
\mc{8}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\ \hline
aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\ \hline
\endhead
\hline \mc{8}{r}{\emph{ Continued on next page }} \\
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

which does not contain a X column. I would like to obtain a correct multi-page table utilizing the `{lr@{--}p{1.3cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.6cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{2.1cm}p{0.7cm}}` format. Could you please help me how to rewrite this code to obtain a correct table?

Comment: Your requirements appear to be mutually exclusive. E.g., the width of the current `tabularx` environment is less than `\textwidth`. By switching to a setup with one or more columns of type `X`, the table's width will increase to `\textwidth`. However, that seems to be expressly forbidden, since you've also written that "the output format of the table cannot change". Or is the width of a table not part of its format? What gives?

Comment: Could we chat on this problem?

Comment: Please edit your posting to clarify your objectives.

Comment: Edited. Could you please check it?

Comment: Since you seem to have hit on a  format that's to your liking, and since the width is less than `\textwidth`, why don't you just define a `longtable`?

Comment: Can you provide a `longtable` version of this code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89636/discussion-between-roloka-and-mico).

Comment: Are the column widths in the table preamble stuck to the indicated values, or are the ratios of the widths more important?

Answer (score 3):

Since the table's width is slightly less than `\textwidth`, there seems to be no need for the `tabularx`-related overhead. Instead, just use a `longtable` to typeset the material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,
               unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,
            left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,
            showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}
\ifdefined\mc
   \renewcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\else
   \newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\fi

\begin{document} 
\begin{longtable}{ l r @{--} p{1.3cm} >{\centering}p{2.6cm} 
                   *{5}{p{1.25cm}} p{2.1cm} p{0.7cm} }               
%% headers and footers

\caption{Table} \\ 
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead

\mc{10}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\ 
\hline
aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\mc{10}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\hline\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of table

aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just two quick question: how to reduce left and right margins around the table? I tried to use \setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm} and \setlength\LTright{-2.5cm} but they are not working. :(

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "reduce left and right margins around the table". For sure, the `longtable` fits (just) inside the textblock.

Comment: `\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}` defines 3.5 and 2.5 cm margins on the left and right sides, respectively. I would like to use 0.5 and 0.5 cm for them, but only around the table (my tables are too wide).

Comment: @Roloka - I don't understand: the total width of the `longtable` is *less* than `\textwidth`. By the way, rather than make the table even wider, I'd reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace.

Comment: @Roloka -- Do you want me to delete this answer as it evidently doesn't address your real, though unstated, formatting requirments?